# User Defined Language in np++ : how can I define folding using the line just before a keyword

Tags: notepad++, abaqus

I'm trying to define a User Defined Language for Abaqus files (*.inp).
I want to define folding to be able to fold the `*Node` chapter :

```
*Node
1,  2,  3
...
...
5, 77.4 , 45
*Element, type=C3D8
```

When I define the language with `*Node` as **open** and `*` as **close** the line `*Element, type=C3D8` is folded too.
Is there a way to make the folding stops just before the line he is supposed to?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to take something existing and modify it? http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files

Comment: I have thought of this but the text shouldn't be modified in my case.